# jQuery clone creating multiple of same div

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that works almost perfectly, but it's cloning the same div multiple times.

Unfortunately, once you select it and deselect it once, it starts showing multiples if you select any others. I'm assuming this has something to do with the cloning.

```
function selectGameItem() {

    $('.inventory-item').on('change', function() {

        var cloneDiv = $(this).clone();

        if($(this).parent('.game-inventory').length) {

            $('.receive-window').append(cloneDiv);
            $(this).addClass('selected-item');

        } else {

            $(this).remove();
            $('.game-label-' + inventoryValue).removeClass('selected-item');

        }

        selectGameItem();

    });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to `selectGameItem();` that is the last line of your `change` handler. It will call `.on('change')` for elements that already have handlers, so next time the event occurs duplicate handlers will run, then when they run they call `selectGameItem()` again and bind *more* handlers, etc.

If you had that line there in order to bind the `change` handler to the cloned items, you don't need that. You can [use `.clone(true)` to clone the event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents) too. *Or*, probably better, just use a delegated event handler by changing this line:

```
$('.inventory-item-hold').on('change', function() {
```

to:

```
$(document).on('change', '.inventory-item-hold', function() {
```

That will automatically work with any elements that are added dynamically that have the `'.inventory-item-hold'` class. (Ideally you wouldn't use `document`, you'd use whatever the nearest common ancestor element is for all of the `'.inventory-item-hold'` elements.)

Comment: I removed it but now it doesn't go when an item is selected a second time (i.e. to remove it). I'm new to this jQuery/Javascript stuff.

Comment: See my edit. (Note that you aren't selecting an item for a second time, you are selecting the clone for a first time.)

Comment: `.clone(true)` is all I needed after removing it from the function wrapper (and didn't call it again in the `change` handler). Thanks a lot for the help!